# Why not say ‘on second thought’?

Tags: word-usage

I see a phrase: on second thoughts. But I feel that it should be ‘on second thought’.

Because we usually say ‘This is the second time’ and do not say ‘This is the second times’.

Comment: It's always singular *What are your **thoughts** on the matter?* For your specific context, check out [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+on+second+thought+he%2Cbut+on+second+thoughts+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20on%20second%20thought%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20on%20second%20thoughts%20he%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbut%20on%20second%20thought%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20on%20second%20thoughts%20he%3B%2Cc0), showing that ***BrE*** massively favours plural, but ***AmE*** is about equally split between singular/plural.

Answer (score 2):

**On second thoughts** and **on second thought** are established expressions that mean the same thing.

Both are used in situations in which a speaker is changing his/her mind about something, often a decision, expressed a few seconds earlier.

Google Books Ngram viewer finds the singular form twice as popular as the plural.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-second-thoughts-on-second-thought
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20second%20thought
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+second+thought%2Con+second+thoughts

Comment: I was initially skeptical about the two forms both being "reasonably" common (that's certainly not *my* experience). But per my NGram link below the question, it turns out this is because there's quite a big split between AmE and BrE usage.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dialect difference to me. I have never heard “on second thoughts” and I am American. And [the Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has very few hits for the plural:

[image]

On the other hand, the reverse is true of the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

[image]